# From and To date picker are allow to choose the date with in 'x' months

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="row spacer">
    <label for="fromdate" class="col-md-4">Date : </label>
    <div  class="col-md-8"> 
      <div class="row">
        <div  class="col-md-6"> 
          <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control input-sm" size="10" uib-datepicker-popup="{{'dd-MM-yyyy'}}" ng-model="srchctrl.startDate" is-open="srchctrl.status.openedS" datepicker-options="srchctrl.dateOptions" uib-tooltip="dd-MM-yyyy" date-disabled="srchctrl.disabled(date)" show-weeks='false' close-text="Close" ng-click="srchctrl.open('S')" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" alt-input-formats="srchctrl.altInputFormats" ng-change="srchctrl.validateDateRange('main')"/>
          <button type="button" class="datepicker-btn" ng-click="srchctrl.open('S')"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">                            
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  size="10" uib-datepicker-popup="{{'dd-MM-yyyy'}}" ng-model="srchctrl.endDate" is-open="srchctrl.status.openedE"  datepicker-options="srchctrl.dateOptions" uib-tooltip="dd-MM-yyyy" date-disabled="srchctrl.disabled(date)" show-weeks='false' close-text="Close" ng-click="srchctrl.open('E')"  placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" alt-input-formats="srchctrl.altInputFormats"  ng-change="srchctrl.validateDateRange('main')"/>
          <button type="button" class="datepicker-btn"  ng-click="srchctrl.open('E')" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

both the date picker are allow to choose the date with in 'x' months.

Suppose x is 3, then if I select 15-01-2017 then other date will alow only till 15-04-2017.

How can I achieve this in the date picker?

Answer (score 0):

**Use max-date attribute**

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                              <div class="row spacer">
                                <label for="fromdate" class="col-md-4">Date : </label>
                                <div  class="col-md-8"> 
                                  <div class="row">
                                   <div  class="col-md-6"> 
                                      <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus"  class="form-control input-sm"  size="10" uib-datepicker-popup="{{'dd-MM-yyyy'}}" ng-model="srchctrl.startDate" is-open="srchctrl.status.openedS"  datepicker-options="srchctrl.dateOptions" uib-tooltip="dd-MM-yyyy" date-disabled="srchctrl.disabled(date)" show-weeks='false' close-text="Close" ng-click="srchctrl.open('S')"  placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"  alt-input-formats="srchctrl.altInputFormats"  ng-change="srchctrl.validateDateRange('main')"/>
                                      <button type="button" class="datepicker-btn" ng-click="srchctrl.open('S')"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                   </div>
                                   <div  class="col-md-6">                            
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  size="10" uib-datepicker-popup="{{'dd-MM-yyyy'}}" ng-model="srchctrl.endDate" is-open="srchctrl.status.openedE"  datepicker-options="srchctrl.dateOptions" uib-tooltip="dd-MM-yyyy" date-disabled="srchctrl.disabled(date)" show-weeks='false' close-text="Close" ng-click="srchctrl.open('E')"  placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" alt-input-formats="srchctrl.altInputFormats"  ng-change="srchctrl.validateDateRange('main')"/>
                                      <button type="button" class="datepicker-btn"  ng-click="srchctrl.open('E')"  max-Date="maxDate"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                   </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.maxDate=srchctrl.startDate;
```

//in controller opon function srchctrl.open('E')

```
var month=srchctrl.startDate.getMonth();

$scope.maxDate.setMonth(month+3);
```